# How can I map my Spring URL to a JSP file in /WEB-INF/views?

Tags: java, spring, mapping

I'm having trouble doing a Spring (using 3.0.5.RELEASE) mapping.  I want to map the URL http://mydomain/context-path/user/registrationform.jsp to my JSP page at

```
/WEB-INF/views/user/registrationform.jsp
```

but I'm getting a 404.  I have my controller setup like so …

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("registrationform.jsp")
public class RegistrationController {

    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RegistrationController.class);
    …
    public void setRegistrationValidation(
        RegistrationValidation registrationValidation) {
        this.registrationValidation = registrationValidation;
    }

    // Display the form on the get request
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegistration(Map model) {
        final Registration registration = new Registration();
        model.put("registration", registration);
        return "user/registrationform";
    }
```

here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml …

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

```
<!-- Enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc... -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.burrobuie.eventmaven" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/messages" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

and here is my web.xml …

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What else do I need to configure (or configure differently) to make this mapping work?  This is harder than  - Dave

Answer (score 1):

Change the `RequestMapping` to:

```
@RequestMapping("/user/registrationform.jsp")
```

Comment: Simple and great.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("registrationform.jsp")
public class RegistrationController {
```

The RequestMapping annotation at class level should be use for a common url pattern like "item/*" and all the links that contains "/item" followed by other pattern would be mapped it to the controller. "user/" in your case
The RequestMapping annotation at method level is used for mapping the sub URL like "item/add" or "item/delete", "registrationform.jsp' in your case
So try this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class RegistrationController {

    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RegistrationController.class);
    …
    public void setRegistrationValidation(
        RegistrationValidation registrationValidation) {
        this.registrationValidation = registrationValidation;
    }

    // Display the form on the get request
    @RequestMapping(value="/registrationform.jsp",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegistration(Map model) {
        final Registration registration = new Registration();
        model.put("registration", registration);
        return "user/registrationform";
    }
```

This will map /user/registrationform.jsp

Comment: I changed my code to what you suggested but I'm still getting the 404.  I confirmed through debugging that my "showRegistration" is never called.  Are the view-resolver in the "dispatcher-servlet.xml" and the web.xml declarations correct?

Comment: It's ok! check if you have in your dispatcher-servlet this:

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

And try with @RequestMapping("/user/*") at class level instead of @ @RequestMapping("/user")

Comment: I included my complete dispatcher-servlet.xml in my question, which includes the "mvc:annotation-drive" tag you mention.  Also, I changed the class level mapping to "/user/*" but even with these changes, I still get a 404.  Is there a smaller test I can run to see if mapping is working at all?