# Mapping Controller URLs to JSP in WEB-INF

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to Spring and I would like to map some URLs to JSP pages. I am trying this for 2 hours now, but I can't get it working. I am sure this is very simple, but I am new to Spring. I am using Spring Boot.

(Yes, I found topics like [How can I map my Spring URL to a JSP file in /WEB-INF/views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607053/how-can-i-map-my-spring-url-to-a-jsp-file-in-web-inf-views), but in my opinion I am doing everything right...)

This is my Controller. If I put a breakpoint there, it gets called. Therefore I think something is wrong with the ViewResolver...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("customers")
public class WebController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String customers(Locale locale, Model model) {
        return "customers";
    }
}
```

This is my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (I am using Spring Security):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//Some other methods, not relevant for this

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
   }
}
```

And my JSP-file is placed in WEB-INF/views/customers.jsp.
When I call localhost:8080/customers/ I get (this is the only error. No others in server log...):

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Aug 11 14:18:47 CEST 2014
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Comment: Your question lacks some details : does your application uses root context (or do you use spring-boot) ? Are there any other errors in the server logs (I hope there are ...) ?

Comment: I am using Spring Boot.
There are no other errors in the server logs :-(

Comment: It looks like spring `dispatcher-servlet` is not started. Have you `@EnableWebMvc` annotation on a configuration class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Serge Ballesta I figured it out. :-)

I needed a configuration class which extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and is annotated with @EnableWebMvc. There I need to override the methods below. Annotating only WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with @EnableWebMvc is not enough and results in "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI...."

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
   }
}
```